# Using semicolon ; to give an attribute multiple values in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I would like to instead of this:

```
<person>
    <forename>Charles</forename>
    <forename>Theodore</forename>
    <forename>Maximilian</forename>
</person>
```

do this:

```
<person forename="Charles; Theodore; Maximilian"/>
```

this passes as well formatted on first sight, unlike for example:

```
<person forename="Charles; Theo&dore; Maximilian"/>
```

Which throws error as not well formatted in visual studio, prompting me to guess the semicolon on the other hand is indeed well formatted and the attribute will be parsed correctly.

In addition to this I've seen Qt code like this elsewhere:

```
#include <qdom.h>
#include <qstring.h>


int main(){
  QDomDocument doc;
  QDomElement root = doc.createElement("root");
  doc.appendChild(root);
  QDomElement elem = doc.createElement("test");


  elem.setAttribute("arg", "value1;value2;value3");


 root.appendChild(elem);
  qDebug("%s", doc.toString().ascii());

  return 0;
}
```

However I'm not very experienced with all the xml parsing, **will the attribute be correctly parsed in the most prevalent (production environment) xml parsers?** Human readability + shortness are atm most important goals, but at what cost is a valid question ofc.

Comment: You already found the most obvious source for bugs (encoded entities). Is a list of items that less human readable?

Comment: By decreasing the amount of lines, one gets better overview on the branching structure (before having to scroll), that's what I meant/am after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semicolon causes no problems in XML. The reason why

```
<person forename="Charles; Theo&dore; Maximilian"/>
```

is problematic is because of the `&` which needs to be represented as `&amp;` if it doesn't start an entity:

```
<person forename="Charles; Theo&amp;dore; Maximilian"/>
```

As attributes in XML can only have one value, all canonical XPath implementations will interpret the string as a single value. Splitting the string on semicolons must be implemented on the application level; but you can still ask XPath for

```
//person[contains(@forename, 'Theodore')]
```

Comment: Yes(I've already taken a look at the w3c xml specifications), but how will the xml parsers (that you're familiar with in your work environment) interpret this attribute with it's multiple ; separated key values?

Comment: @DeveloperDoge: As a string. Splitting the string on semicolons must be done on the application level.

Comment: So you're saying the xml parsers that you use/know will ignore the ; as part of the string?

Comment: @DeveloperDoge: They'll take it as a part of the string, same way as space or `h` or any other character.

Comment: I just tried XPath /person[@forename!="Theodore"] and get back the person element. Meaning the element doesn't have a forename with Theodore as value in the eyes of XPath. As I assume XPath is the most used tool for parsing/querying the xml data, I think this gives a final answer to my question, with it being: "No, this attribute will not be parsed as containing 3 values by most popular xml parsers". Could you edit your answer to contain this quoted phrase, then I can accept as a direct answer to my question. Also include your last comment please.

Comment: @DeveloperDoge: Updated.